# APC __PHP_Incomplete_Class_Name

Tags: php, apc

I am learning the use of APC in PHP. I have created this script to test it:

```
<?php

require 'Person.php';

if (!$p = apc_fetch('p')) {
    $p = new Person('larry');
    apc_store('p', $p);
}

echo $p->getName();
```

where Person.php is:

```
<?php

class Person
{
    private $_name;

    public function __construct($_name)
    {
        $this->_name = $_name;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $name
     */
    public function setName($_name)
    {
        $this->_name = $_name;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->_name;
    }
}
```

It works fine but the stored value in apc is:

```
__PHP_Incomplete_Class::__set_state(array(
'__PHP_Incomplete_Class_Name' => 'Person',
'_name' => 'larry',
))
```

is it ok? or there is something wrong with '__PHP_Incomplete_Class_Name'

Thank you

Comment: Where is the problem exactly?

Comment: 1) Don't learn APC, it's replaced with OPCache. 2) There is no problem.

Comment: ibu, that's the question, I don't know if '__PHP_Incomplete_Class_Name' is a problem or not?

Comment: N.B. thank you, I will try OPCache

Comment: __PHP_Incomplete_Class_Name is normally caused by trying to access an object when you don't have a definition for the class.  Ensure that you are loading the class definition before accessing it.

Answer (score 2):

Whilst I don't know APC, `__PHP_Incomplete_Class_Name` is normally caused by trying to access an object when you don't have a definition for the class

You often see this when calling `session_start` before you have included or required your class structures, or unserializing something when you do not have its definition.

Ensure that you are loading the class definition (either include or require) before accessing it when you're loading back out of APC and I imagine everything should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

Just had the same problem and solved this way...
The problem is not the way you are saving, the problem is that when you are reading the object, php try to access the object name and contructions but doesnt find it.
Try just adding your require 'Person.php'; on the page you want to read the object properties and see if that works. hope it helps.